# Using subqueries to build nested object in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure if this is possible in mysql, but I'm trying to build a nested object out of a query instead of php.  I have a db of survey results, and I want to build an object who's keys are the question and value is an array/object of the answers.  Is this possible?  I'm using something like this:

```
SELECT 
ss.*,
    (SELECT int_value FROM `SubmittedQuestions` AS su WHERE ss.id = su.submitted_survey_id)
FROM
`SubmittedSurveys` as ss;
```

Do I have to build this object in PHP?  My issue is that I'm doing all these loops in PHP and I think it's taking a while to build the objects whereas if I could do it in mysql I think it'd be one fast query.  Let me know what your thoughts are on this issue.

I'm looking for an object like this:

Survey: {
   Question 1: [
      answer 1,
      answer 2],
   Question 2: [
      answer 1,
      answer 2]
}

So what I'm currently doing in php is querying all survey questions from one table, then with that object, I loop through and query for each question and get the answers from another table.  If there are a lot of questions this design will be super slow, can anybody suggest an alternative?

Comment: MySQL deals with row-based data, that's it. There is no simple, *sane* way to nest data the way you are asking. You can use joins, but you will end up with quite a bit of duplicate data to pare out.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that's what I feared.  So would you suggest handling small bits of data at a time?  Or maybe display question and when clicked on, do an AJAX call to get it's answers?

Comment: I am a fan of only pulling the minimum amount of data you need when you need it, and caching where possible.

Answer (score 7):

The way you have described that you're already doing is probably best. You can retrieve everything in one go using JOINs, eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM surveys s INNER JOIN questions q
  ON s.id = q.survey_id
  INNER JOIN answers a
  ON q.id = a.question_id
WHERE s.id = $submitted_survey_id
```

And your results will look like:

```
survey1,question1,answer1
survey1,question1,answer2
survey1,question1,answer3
survey1,question2,answer1
survey1,question2,answer2
survey1,question2,answer3
survey1,question3,answer1
survey1,question3,answer2
survey1,question3,answer3
...
```

But you'll still have to write logic to pull those results apart into a sane data structure, and you're retrieving a lot of duplicate data from the database.

SQL in general does not produce hierarchical result sets, you have to produce those through your application one way or another.